# Angular Primeng Datatable retain row expand after saving?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am expanding a row from datatable and trying to click the hyperlink to open a modal popup and saving the details, but the problem is after saving the data the expanded rows are collpased due to Store dispatch action.

```
    save(model) {
    const post = {
        'firstName': model.value.firstName,
        'lastName': model.value.lastName,
        'age': model.value.age,
    };
    this.serviceCall.updateData(post).subscribe((data: ResponseMessage) => {
        if (data.success) {
            this.closeModalWindow();
            this.store.dispatch(new LoadDataAction());
        } else {
            this.serviceCall.handleError(Error);
        }
    });
}
```

Please let me know, how to retain the selected expanded row after saving the data. Any clue..?

Comment: have you tried $interval(function() {
 }, 2000);

Comment: No. Do i have to call interval before subscribe while saving the data..?

Comment: yes try doing that, i am not sure because if you bind data with the dom it will refresh. so you have to do some Dom manipulation in the code to show the scenario.

Comment: Not working as expected. Most probably, I would like to handle the datatable with selected expandedRows..I guess

Comment: It should be yes

Comment: have you tried async while loading the data? Ex: in html :   <p-table body [value]="samplingSupplies$ | async"

Comment: @RagavanRajan: Not working as expected..

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz please ?

Comment: @Antikhippe: Please find my StackBlitz here : https://angular-primeng-datatable.stackblitz.io . After saving the comments on the individual row expansion , I would require to preserve the expanded row after the save service call.

Comment: I tried opening that stackblitz. It's not working for me

Comment: @Nico: Trye this one.. https://angular-primeng-datatable-gg3kge.stackblitz.io/